# Retool: Action button to open modal with container

Tags: retool

I have a table in retool.  I've added an "action" column with buttons and renamed them "edit".  What I would like to do on click of the action button is to open a modal with the data in the row populated.  A user should be able to see the values of the row, edit them and when he clicks "submit" it will send an update API call for that row's unique id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We’re working on some new docs for modal components, but until then here’s what you can do:

1. Drag a modal component onto your canvas. It’s going to appear as a button that opens a model, but don’t worry about that just yet
2. Create a Javascript query in the query editor that opens the modal. If we’re working with the default names, your query would be `modal1.open()`
3. Configure the action button in your table to run that JS query on click

That’s a quick way to open a modal through an action button. In terms of what’s in that modal, you can drag any components you want and reference table properties. So if you wanted to display a user’s email, you could drag a text component into the model and set its value to `table1.selectedRow.data.email`.

The last thing to deal with is the button, which you probably don’t want since you’re opening the modal via action buttons. You can hide it by clicking on it, heading to the inspector in the right sidebar, and scrolling down to the “display” settings. Just put `true` into the “Hide when true” field and the button won’t show.

Comment: We added this to our docs! https://docs.retool.com/docs/working-with-modals

Answer (score 0):

hello stack overflow family this is my first post.
we are facing same issue today so i used one trick for opening a modal in action, i run one query that query name is model_open and in success event i select modal open and this query is triggered in Action edit option ,

i hope my first post help you ... :)